# Total number doesnt fit numbers of hits returned

Tags: elasticsearch

I accidently found, that 'total' number in search result doesnt fit the number of 'hits' items returned. I noticed this when only a few items returned for given query so it was easily to check/notice in search result.  For example the query as below:

```
{
   "from" : 1,
   "size" : 9,
   "query" : {
     "bool" : {
       "must" : {
         "query_string" : {
           "query" : "quad",
           "default_field" : "_all"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

... returns response like this:

```
"hits":{"total":8,"max_score":1.2086515,"hits":[...]}
```

... which says there is 8 items in result but 'hits' array contains only 7 items. I tried different search queries (that returns up to 9 items, as it is my 'size' limit) and the 'hits' array size was total-1 . How it could be that it doesnt fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch would return `size-from` results in the `hit` array. From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html#search-request-from-size) :

> from defines the offset from the first result you want to fetch.

In the query provided in OP this would be equal to 8 results.
If you want 9 results you should set `from:0` that is include the first result.

Example:

```
 {
   "from" : 0,
   "size" : 9,
   "query" : {
     "bool" : {
       "must" : {
         "query_string" : {
           "query" : "quad",
           "default_field" : "_all"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How could I overlook the "from":1  :-( Thanks a lot!!